# openid connect to identify server in php

Tags: php, openid-connect

I'm using https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP this library to auth an user from identify server 4.
I'm trying to connect to identify server which has this settings

```
Scope : offline_access
Response type: code id_token
DefaultScheme = “Cookie”
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client
Invalid grant type for client
```

My code

```
$issuer = 'issuer';
$cid = 'clientid';
$secret = 'clientsecret';
$oidc = new Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient($issuer, $cid, $secret);
$oidc->addScope(array('openid', 'offline_access'));
$oidc->authenticate();
$oidc->requestUserInfo('sub');
$user = $oidc->requestUserInfo();
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```